# Deleting non-matching entries in two "Time" columns, and at the same time, delete their associated "Value" entries

Tags: excel

Hopefully I can describe my issue in a way that makes sense. Essentially what I have going on is that I have four columns such as follows (there are two columns of times, and associated values with them). The issue is that the first column contains more "Times" than the third column does. Therefore, I want to remove any non-matching "Times" between both columns. However, since both columns have associated "Values" with them, I want to also delete any of those values at the same time, if their associated "Time" value is also deleted. Is there a way to do this in Excel?

Here's an example of what I mean. My data is structured as follows; I have four columns; each with sets of times/temperatures. However, in the first set, it has one more sample than the second set, because the second set skips from the 58th second to 1:00. What I want to do therefore, is delete the 59th second and its associated temperature from the first set, so that both sets end up with the same amount of samples/times, and I can do a plot to compare the two sets.

```
Time1                Temperature1   Time2                  Temperature2
2017-10-19 10:00:55     69.45       2017-10-19 10:00:55       73.4
2017-10-19 10:00:56     69.52       2017-10-19 10:00:56       73.4
2017-10-19 10:00:57     69.52       2017-10-19 10:00:57       73.4
2017-10-19 10:00:58     69.60       2017-10-19 10:00:58       73.4
2017-10-19 10:00:59     69.60       2017-10-19 10:01:00       73.4
2017-10-19 10:01:00     69.76       2017-10-19 10:01:01       73.4
2017-10-19 10:01:01     69.68
```

Comment: Can you clarify what the columns/data look like? Also, what's your expected output in your example table above?

Comment: Essentially the problem is that I'm trying to compare two sets of temperature data; except one set is second by second, while the other set sometimes skips seconds. Therefore there's a discrepancy in the amount of samples. To be able to plot both together, I want to eliminate the extra samples from the first set

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add an extra column in your data set and add the formula =IFERROR(IF(MATCH(A1,C:C,0),1,0),0). Then copy it down to all the other rows.  You can then filter on anything that has a 0 in that column, those are your extra samples.